# I am learning to do stacking. I want to know what will the input be to level 2 classifiers

Tags: boosting, ensemble-learning, stacking

In classification/regression problems, say if we use five different base classifiers, we get 5 predictions for each example. What would be the input to the second level classifiers?

Answer (score 1):

Say you have **5 base-estimators** and **1 meta-estimator** (that will be trained on the predictions of your 5 base-estimators).

The first step is to train your base estimators. You should think of it like a bit like performing a 5-fold cross validation. Split your training set into 5 parts and train each of the models on four of those parts, while holding the fifth out for prediction. Each model should be trained on a **different** combination of training folds and have a different fold for prediction. In detail:

- The **1st** model: Training folds $(1, 2, 3, 4)$. Prediction fold: $5$
- The **2nd** model: Training folds $(1, 2, 3, 5)$. Prediction fold: $4$
- The **3rd** model: Training folds $(1, 2, 4, 5)$. Prediction fold: $3$
- The **4th** model: Training folds $(1, 3, 4, 5)$. Prediction fold: $2$
- The **5th** model: Training folds $(2, 3, 4, 5)$. Prediction fold: $1$

Now, by combining the predictions of the 5 base-estimators, we have the predictions of the **whole dataset**. These predictions will be the **training set of the meta-estimator**! Because these originated from the initial training set, we have their actual labels.

Finally, if we want to **evaluate** the performance of the stacked classifier, we need to follow the same path we did during training. Namely, the test data should be **first** passed to each of the base-estimators for prediction. Then, these predictions are **averaged** and passed as **input** to the meta-estimator. Finally, the predictions of the meta-estimator are **compared** with the actual labels for evaluation.

The whole procedure is depicted in the following figure:

[image]

You can also read [this](http://blog.kaggle.com/2017/06/15/stacking-made-easy-an-introduction-to-stacknet-by-competitions-grandmaster-marios-michailidis-kazanova/) blog post for more information on model stacking.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but how do we interpret the inputs to the meta estimator.What do those inputs signify?

Comment: Nothing. The input features for the meta-estimator don't have a physical interpretation, if that's what you're looking for. Each feature is simply the predictions of a base-estimator on a given dataset. The goal of the meta-estimator is to define a strategy on what base-estimator should count more or less for the final prediction. Intuitively, you can look at this like this: each base-estimator has its advantages and limitations; the meta-estimator tries to find a way to use all of the advantages of all base-estimators to get the best results.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the information leakage of the method depicted above. It can give you much lower validation error vs test error and not generalize well. I experienced it and it was quite shocking, on a fairly small dataset.

See this post: https://www.kaggle.com/general/18793